# Multidimension array sorting in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort this array in ascending order by 'money'.

Here is my input array.

```
$array = array(
            array(
               'user' => array(
                   'money' => 4,
                   'fname' => 'abc'
                ),
           ),
            array(
               'user' => array(
                   'money' => 2,
                   'fname' => 'def'
               ),
            ),
            array(
               'user' => array(
                   'money' => 8,
                   'fname' => 'FGH'
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'user' => array(
                    'money' => 5,
                    'fname' => 'xYz'
                ),
            )
        );
```

Comment: I have checked the above link can you please check my array. My input array has 'user' key

Comment: So, simply add `user`: `$a['order']` => `$a['user']['money']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cmp_sort($x,$y) {           //Your function to compare two keys
    if ($x===$y)
        return 0;
    else
        return ($x>$y?1:-1);
}

uasort($array,'cmp_sort');    //Call user-defined compare function
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);    
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is working. How can I use this ascending or descending by parameter.

Comment: You may change this  return ($x>$y?1:-1); to  return ($x>$y?-1:1); if it's descending. In that case, we can pass an extra parameter and use another if.